# Reducing polynomial from Weierstrass substitution from n-degree to n/2-degree

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, reduction-formula, weierstrass-factorization

If you have an 8th degree polynomial $f(t)$, and you know that despite 8 solutions, there are 4 solutions $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3$ but the other 4 solutions are $2*\arctan(x0)+\pi, 2*\arctan(x1)+\pi, 2*\arctan(x2)+\pi$ and $2*\arctan(x3)+\pi$, is there a way to factor the polynomial to a 4th degree polynomial?

For example, you can expand the form:

$f(t) = (t - x_0)(t - x_1)(t - x_2)(t - x_3)(t - [2\arctan(x_0) + \pi])(t - [2\arctan(x_1) + \pi])(t - [2\arctan(x_2) + \pi])(t - [2\arctan(x_3) + \pi])$

And then equate coefficients of $f(t)$

But it seems a system of equations involving $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,\arctan(x_0),\arctan(x_1),\arctan(x_2),\arctan(x_3)$ may be difficult to solve unless such a technique is known?

Original problem:
An equation of form $Z+A*\sin(x)+B*\cos(x)+C*\sin^2(x)+D*\sin(x)\cos(x)+E*\sin^3(x)+F*\sin^2(x)\cos(x)+G*\sin^4(x)+H*\cos(x)*\sin^3(x)$

leads to such a Weierstrass equation where the solutions will be ${x, x+\pi}$ for $x$ in the solutions.  It is a general form (after $\cos^2(x)$ is replaced by $(1-\sin^2(x)$).

We can assume $Z=0$ or the solutions may not occur at the assumed $\pi$ intervals.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I think it is correct now.

Comment: The reference to the Weierstrass substitution in the title hints at this being a step in solving another problem. It would be better to post the problem you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: Ok fair enough, the original can be asked.  Updated for that purpose.

Comment: In general it's not true that if $x$ is a solution of $0 = Z + A \sin x + B \cos x + \cdots$ so is $x + \pi$. For example, if $A = Z = 1$, $B = \cdots = H = 0$, then $x = \frac\pi2$ is a solution but $\frac\pi2 + \pi = \frac{3\pi}2$ is not.

Comment: Ah thank you for this important point.  I suppose if $Z=0$, then it would be true?  Due to reduction where you get $\sqrt(Q^2+R^2)\sin(x+\arctan(Q/R))$ and hence $\arcsin(0)=0,\pi$

Comment: No, essentially because some terms reverse sign under $x \mapsto x + \pi$ but other terms are fixed. The ones that are fixed are those whose total degree (regarded as a polynomial in $\sin x, \cos x$) is even.

Comment: Applying the Weierstrass substitution yields a general octic, i.e., for any octic polynomial $p(t)$ we can find an expression $g(x) = Z + A \sin x + B \cos x + \cdots$ such that the $g(2 \arctan x) = \frac{p(t)}{(1 + t^2)^4}$, in other words we can't expect any nontrivial relation among the roots of $g(x)$ other than $2 \pi$ periodicity.

Comment: Interesting.  So I suppose a sort of symbolic solution is likely impossible.  I have noticed that the imaginary roots are often at $0+1i$ and $0-1i$, and often there are only 4 real roots.  Ive also in practice noticed septics.  But Ive never seen 8 real solutions.  Which made it seem that in my specific problem domain, some sort of reduction must be possible.  But I am starting to concede the point that $\pi$ periodicity is not going to happen in these cases.

Comment: I'm going to post my true original problem (solving a more simple system of 2 partial derivatives).  As it is what led to the false assumptions.